# Discord.js Embed Timestamp not able to parse a UNIX timestamp

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When trying to edit a discord message into a RichEmbedded message using discord.js, I get the error

```
(node:10860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.timestamp: Could not parse 1581492006141. Should be ISO8601.
    at item.request.gen.end (/rbd/pnpm-volume/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/11.5.1/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (/rbd/pnpm-volume/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/snekfetch/3.6.4/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I am hosting the bot on glitch.com. I am sending a message to a channel, then later editing it into an embedded message that contains the requested data.

```
msg.channel.send("Recieving Data").then(response => {
  //Get data
  response.edit({
    embed: {
      description: "Example Data",
      timestamp: msg.createdTimestamp
    }
  })
}).catch(//handle error);
```

It does not error if I send the embed message instead of editing a previous message. I've tried parsing the timestamp yet it does not accept it. Is it because the previous message's timestamp cannot be changed after being sent?

Comment: In Discord, the timestamp of embed is a ISO8601 timestamp, does discord.js use ISO8601 timestamp too on createdTimestamp ? Else you will have to add 3 "0" at the end of your timestamp

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama From what I understand, createdTimestamp gives UNIX time as a number value(i.e. 1581532642193), it does not have trouble parsing it normally but it does if I edit a previous message with the embed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Date with your timestamp, Discord don't accept timestamp in this field, [only ISO8601 date](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object)

You can do it like this :

```js
...

msg.channel.send("Recieving Data").then(response => {
  //Get data
  response.edit({
    embed: {
      description: "Example Data",
      timestamp: msg.createdAt
    }
  })
}).catch(//handle error);

...
```

How ever, if you want a quick and easy way of designing an embed, try out this tool by leovoel, the [Embed Visualizer](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) shows you exactly how your embed will look, and will generate the code for you at the press of a button. With that you will see that the timestamp field doesn't accept timestamp.

Comment: [`Message.createdAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createdAt) is the date version of the timestamp, no need to convert it.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit embed timeStamp, but in your sulution you try edit msg with only timestamp field. So you got an error. `msg.edit()` don`t change the part of content, this method change full message content.

So like if you have embed with `description, footer, fields`. And you will edit him with **only** `description` field of data, other fields of embed will be removed.

```js
    embed: {
      //Data
      description: "someText"
    }
```

Right way will be get message content, embeds and change reciving data embed timeStamp and then edit message with new data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't bother adding the description fields to the example code since I didn't think it was relevant, in my actual code I do have all necessary fields made. I'll make it more clear in the example.

Comment: Hmmmm, try `timestamp:new Date(msg.createdTimestamp).toISOString();`

Comment: That did the charm, not sure why it couldn't parse it before though.